# Copying RTF to MS Word cause OLE error 0x800A177F

Tags: ms-word, oledb, ole, ibm-doors

I'm writing DXL script for export and format requirements from **DOORS to MS Word**.To speed up an export i'm creating tables in RTF format and pasting them directly to Word document.

```
void directCopy(Buffer b)
{
    ClipboardLock cl = null
    while(null cl)
    {
        cl = create(2000)
        if(null cl)
        {
            if(!confirm("Unable to lock clipboard. Retry?"))
            {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    if(!null cl)
    {
        noError
        setRichClip(b, false)
        oleResult(oleMethod(objSelection, cMethodPaste))        
        lastError
        delete cl
    }
}
```

Normally script should put content of `b` into clipboard and OLE method should paste it into Word document. But instead of, I'm getting OLE

> error 0x800A177F

Does any one know what this error mean? I tried to google it but nothing pops up.

Comment: No idea what the error means, but a common cause for errors when pasting to Word is when the target `Selection` (or `Range`) object is not a valid location for pasting the clipboard content. One way to test this (and the problem, generally) would be to end the code with the content on the clipboard. As an end-user, without changing the location of the selection, attempt to paste. Can the clipboard contents be pasted? If not, the error shown in the Word window might be more helpful.

Comment: This error is related to invalid RTF stucture. I found it by pasting buffer content into rtf file and opening it in Word.